# Project Euler 92

Tags: python, math

My code for solving [problem 92](http://projecteuler.net/problem=92) was correct but too slow and hence I tried to modify it by considering only one number for each possible permutation of that number, effectively reducing the size of the problem to 11439 from the original 10 million. Here's my code

```
import time
from Euler import multCoeff

start = time.time()

def newNum(n):
    return sum([int(dig)**2 for dig in str(n)])

def chain(n, l):
    if n in l:
        return n, l
    else:
        l.append(n)
        return chain(newNum(n), l)

nums = []

for i in range(1,10000000):
    if all(str(i)[j] <= str(i)[j+1] for j in range(len(str(i))-1)):
        nums.append(i)

count = 0   

for i in nums:
    if 89 in chain(i,[])[1]: 
        perms = multCoeff(i)
        count += perms

end = time.time() - start            

print count, end
```

multCoeff is a method that I created which is basically equivalent to `len(set(permutations([int(j) for j in str(i)])))`
and works just fine. Anyway, the problem is that the result I get is not the correct one, and it looks like I'm ignoring some of the cases but I can't really see which ones. I'd be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: You're worried about reducing the number of chains to the essentially different numbers, but it's much faster to lump together the numbers that have the same sum of squares of digits. The maximum sum of the squares of the digits is 567, and there are 495 possible values. Just remember which of these lead to 89 and which lead to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're missing the code for `multCoeff`, so I'm guessing here.

You're trying to filter from 1 to 999,999,999 by excluding numbers that do not have digits in ascending order and then re-calculating their permutations after.

Your problem is `0`.

According to your filter `2, 20, 200, 2000, 20000, 200000, 2000000` are all represented by `2`, however you're probably not adding back this many permutations.

---

General observations about your code:

- `item in list` has `O(n)` [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity); try to avoid doing this for large lists.
- You are throwing away the results of **many** computations; any number in a chain that results in `89` or `1` will always have that end result.
- Every function call has a time cost; try to keep the number of functions in looping calls low.
- Casting `str` to `int` is somewhat expensive; try to keep the number of casts to a minimum.

Comment: My program is indeed not counting all these permutations, I'll have to factor this is. Thanks for your other suggestions as well!